# This is a cipher leading to the location of a hidden treasure

Tags: cipher

> LNNINDTAETTRLUTERHMEEOTBURRNAITIDALGIUE

Is the string of seemingly random letters given to you in order to determine the location of a hidden treasure.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: Make sure to $\color{green}{\rm Accept}\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$ the correct answer (@TNT 's answer below, most likely) :)

Answer (score 14):

If you:

> start at the beginning and take every third letter (wrapping around at the end so that the third letter is one that has not been used) you get:
> LITTLE MOUNTAIN NATURE TRAIL UNDER THE BRIDGE